# Why Castle Windsor's Typed Factory registered as Singleton lifestyle is Disposed?

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I have very strange situation with Castle Windsor where factory registered as `LifeStyle.Singleton` appears disposed at some point. After couple of hours I was able to simplify production case to this excerpt:

**EDIT**
After some investigation yet I've simplified issue to almost trivial case (original version saved below):

```cs
public interface IFactory {
    IAnotherFactory CreateAnother();
}

public interface IAnotherFactory {
    A CreateA();
}

public class A {}

[Test]
public void IsItABug() {
    Container.Kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    Container.Register(Component.For<A>().LifestyleTransient(),
                       Component.For<IFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleTransient(),
                       Component.For<IAnotherFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleSingleton());

    // uncomment this line to make test pass
    // var makeAnotherUsedInMainContainerScopeBeforeFactoryCreation =
    //     Сontainer.Resolve<IAnotherFactory>();

    var factory = Container.Resolve<IFactory>();
    factory.CreateAnother();
    Container.Release(factory);
    var another = Container.Resolve<IAnotherFactory>();
    another.CreateA(); // throws ObjectDisposedException
}
```

Ant the exception is much shorter now as well:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException : The factory was disposed and can no longer be used.
Object name: 'this'.
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in TypedFactoryInterceptor.cs: line 59
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() in d:\work\16de7b8c88ab14af\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\AbstractInvocation.cs: line 145
   at Castle.Proxies.IAnotherFactoryProxy.CreateA()
   at Castle.Windsor.Tests.Facilities.TypedFactory.Components.TypedFactoryAndSubContainersTestCase.IsItABug() in TypedFactoryAndSubContainersTestCase.cs: line 102
```

I believe now it is not a question anymore, because Windsor has had very similar issue in the past (IOC-345), so I've written failing test and [submitted an issue](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/pull/61)

**Original variant:**

```
public interface IFactory {
    Y CreateY();
    Z CreateZ();
    void Release(Y obj);
}

public class X {
    public X(IFactory factory) {
        var y = factory.CreateY();
        factory.Release(y);
        factory.CreateY();
    }
}

public class Y {
    public Y(IFactory factory) {
        factory.CreateZ();
    }
}

public class Z {
    public Z(IAnotherFactory anotherFactory) {
        anotherFactory.CreateA(); // <--- on second time anotherFactory is disposed already O_o
    }
}

public interface IAnotherFactory {
    A CreateA();
}

public class A {}

[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void IsItABug()
    {
        var c = new WindsorContainer();
        c.Kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        c.Register(Component.For<X>().LifestyleTransient(),
                   Component.For<Y>().LifestyleTransient(),
                   Component.For<Z>().LifestyleTransient(),
                   Component.For<A>().LifestyleTransient(),
                   Component.For<IFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleTransient(),
                   Component.For<IAnotherFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleSingleton());

        c.Resolve<X>();
    }
}
```

On the marked line above with Windsor 3.2 I get the exception:

```
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException : ComponentActivator: could not instantiate Sandbox.GM.Config.X
  ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException : ComponentActivator: could not instantiate Sandbox.GM.Config.Y
  ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException : ComponentActivator: could not instantiate Sandbox.GM.Config.Z
  ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.ObjectDisposedException : The factory was disposed and can no longer be used.
Object name: 'this'.

   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, ref Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve()
   at TestApp.Class1.IsItABug() in Class1.cs: line 56
--TargetInvocationException
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(Type implType, Object[] arguments, ConstructorCandidate constructor)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)
--ComponentActivatorException
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, ref Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve(IKernelInternal kernel, IReleasePolicy scope)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IFactoryProxy.CreateY()
   at TestApp.X..ctor(IFactory factory) in Class1.cs: line 19
--TargetInvocationException
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(Type implType, Object[] arguments, ConstructorCandidate constructor)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)
--ComponentActivatorException
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, ref Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve(IKernelInternal kernel, IReleasePolicy scope)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IFactoryProxy.CreateZ()
   at TestApp.Y..ctor(IFactory factory) in Class1.cs: line 25
--TargetInvocationException
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(Type implType, Object[] arguments, ConstructorCandidate constructor)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType)
--ObjectDisposedException
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IAnotherFactoryProxy.CreateA()
   at TestApp.Z..ctor(IAnotherFactory anotherFactory) in Class1.cs: line 31
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a pretty terrible question title. Please update to a title that describes the problem more accurately. This is important for you to get your question answered and will make it easier for others to find this question in the future (SEO).

Comment: @Steven yeah, I've thought about it myself, but didn't invent something meaningful honestly... I'll try again, thanks

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Comment: @JohnS.not using transient factories, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe now it is a bug, hence the issue: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/pull/61